# Find the distance between two indexes in an array, in clockwise direction

Tags: java

To find the distance between two indexes in an array, where the array needs to be read in clockwise direction.

For example

{**1**, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8 , 9,10,**11**,12}
distance between 11 & 1 is 2 not 10 (because start from 11, 12, 1)

distance between 1 & 11 is 10, as u start counting from 1

I tried following based on many responses on SO but looking for better ways to accommodate direction of movement.

```
   public static int distance2(int l, int p, int c)
    {
        return   Math.min((p - c) % l, (c - p) % l);
    }
```

Recommendation?

Edit: Answer from Mady Daby worked. Thank you.

Comment: Your method doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question. It doesn't even accept an array as a parameter.

Comment: I recommend replacing the obscure variable names with real words.  Good variable names would make the code a lot more readable to humans!  Assuming p and c are the indices of the chosen elements, and l is the length of the array, isn't your code going to return the shortest distance between them rather than the distance in the specified direction?

Comment: @BeHappy - clockwise - there's no notion of clockwise in java.  What you seem to be trying to say is nearest (including wrapping around to the start of the array again)?  So assuming _indexA_, _indexB_ and _length_ the distance is `Math.min((indexB - indexA), (indexB + length - indexA));`

Answer (score 1):

This should give you the clockwise distance between two indices:

```java
public static int distance(int index1, int index2, int size){
    return index1 < index2 ? index2 - index1 : index2 + size - index1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked like charm. distance2(myIntArray, 11,1) = 2 distance2(myIntArray, 1,11) = 10 distance2(myIntArray, 4,7) = 3

Answer (score 1):

The expression you're looking for is `((b - a) + len) % len)`, where `a` is the "from" index, `b` is the "to" index, and `len` is the length of the array.

```
static int clockDist(int fromIdx, int toIdx, int len)
{
    return ((toIdx - fromIdx) + len) % len;
}

public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    System.out.println(clockDist(1, 11, 12));
    System.out.println(clockDist(11, 1, 12));
}
```

Output:

```
10
2
```